# Repacing Text with VBA Find Object

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I want to replace several lines of text in a word doc.
Luckily, the lines I must replace are highlighted and exist on their own respective lines.  I want to remove the highlighting and add an asterisk to the beginning of the line.
Using MSDN documentation I have almost got it.

My sub (pasted below) doesn't quite work.

It **does** remove the highlighting and it does put the original text in place of the old text.

It **does not** add the asterisk to the beginning of the repalaced text.

I think that I am not using the *.Text* member correctly. 
Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

```
Sub mysub2()

ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
    With myRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
            With .Replacement
                Dim mystring As String
                mystring = .Text
                mystring = "*" & mystring
                .Text = mystring
                .ClearFormatting
                .Highlight = False
            End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Format:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: why don't you just do mystring = "*" & .Text ?

Comment: Thanks, that was my first approach.  It did not work. I added the extra step hoping that the mystring variable would allow me to add the asterisk character (it did not).

Comment: put a breakpoint on this line of code  .Text = mystring and see what is the value of "mystring"

Comment: I'm not sure how to use breakpoints. to try and get the same effect I have  added "Debug.Print (mystring = "*" & mystring)" to the sub.  The result is :
*
False

Comment: have you tried just .Text = "*" & .Text

Comment: Yes, this produces the same result.  " * False"

Comment: Correct... you're not using `.Text` properly - in fact you're using 2 different `.Text`.  See here: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/FindReplaceAllWithVBA.htm